# When I filter for a particular column value I get an Empty Dataframe, even though the value exists?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that looks like this:

```
                   order_id  order_price_diff  order_price_lvl_index  
0       1684911859676852148               0.0                      0   
1       1684911859481117955               0.0                      0   
2       1684908603135335916               0.0                      0
```

With many more rows and columns, but the others aren't important.

I would like to query just the row with `order_id == 1684911859481117955`

I tried:

```
>>>res = df.query('order_id == 1684911859481117955') 
>>>res
```

But the above just prints

```
Empty Dataframe 
Columns: ... 
Index : []
```

I have also tried

```
>>> res = df.loc[df['order_id'] == 1684911859481117955]
>>> res
```

But I get the same result. Am I missing something??

Comment: What's the data type of the order_id?

Comment: Sorry, I realised the number is a string... Not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: All good. I think you can mark the question as closed or something.

Comment: We all do it sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `order_id` is a string. Try this one:

```py
res = df.query('order_id == "1684911859481117955"')
```